# Arduino Programming in C: Why output is not the way it supposed to be?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a problem with an arduino program. I'm a beginner.
Everytime I upload this program, the "henti" is always HIGH. It supposed to be LOW after 5 sec.

Please Help me!!

```
void loop()
{
  if digitalRead(manual)==HIGH && digitalRead(pln_in)==HIGH && digitalRead(gen_in)==LOW)
  {
    keadaan1();
  }
}

void keadaan1()
{
  digitalWrite(henti, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(gen_out, LOW);
  digitalWrite(normal, LOW);
  digitalWrite(emergency, LOW);
  digitalWrite(start, LOW);
  digitalWrite(busi, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(pln_out, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(henti, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArduinoLand, the `loop` function is called, stunningly enough, in a loop :-)

In other words, it's as if you had the main function:

```
int main (void) {
    setup();
    for (;;) {         // just call loop() over and over.
        loop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That means that `henti` goes high, waits five seconds, then goes low. Then, assuming the `digitalRead` conditions are still true<sup>(a)</sup>, it loops around and *immediately* goes high again.

If you want it to stay low for a bit before going high again, you should put another `delay(something)` just before the closing brace of your `keadaan1()` function.

If you want that bit of code to only run once, either put it in the `setup()` function or stop the loop function from returning, such as with:

```
for (;;);   // do nothing, forever.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is where some debugging experience comes into its own. Sprinkling some debug statements through out your code can greatly assist with figuring out what the issue is, such as with:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Starting...");
    delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
   if (digitalRead(manual) == HIGH &&
       digitalRead(pln_in) == HIGH &&
       digitalRead(gen_in) == LOW)
   {
    Serial.println("Calling keadaan1");
    keadaan1();
  }
}
```

Comment: I know what to do now. Thank you very much paxdiablo.